# Should we declare a vector as constant globally or pass it in a recursive function in order to reduce memory usage?

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

I need to use a vector array in a recursive function. Should I declare that vector as constant globally or directly pass it from the main function in c++? Which approach is recommended? Does the former approach consume lesser memory than the latter one? Does in each recursive call a separate copy of the vector  array is created?

I don't want to modify the array. I just want to access all the elements of the array in each recursive call. Can someone tell me the difference between the two approaches with respect to memory and time?

1st approach

```
const vector<int> array = {1,2,3,4,5};
void fun(int index)
{
       // some ending condition

      // only access array(no modification)

      // recusive call
      fun(index+1);
}

int main()
{
  fun(a,0);

 return 0;
}
```

2nd approach

```
void fun(vector<int> &array,int index)
{
       // some ending condition

       // only access array(no modification)

      // recusive call
      fun(array,index+1);
}

int main()
{
  vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5};
  fun(a,0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Usually we avoid working with global variables like hell. If you pass the vector as a parameter you probably want to pass as reference not by value.

Comment: Pass it by const reference.

Comment: Another option is to wrap `fun` into a class and make `array` a data member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a section in memory called **the stack**. Your function calls are stored there. You waste memory if you pass a `vector` as value, because each call will have its own copy of it. Instead you will need to pass it as a reference, because in that case the `vector` will be reused.

You can refactor your code to use a `class` instead with this `vector` as its member.

Using a global variable spares a lot of memory, but it's such an anti-pattern, leading to serious problems that you need to avoid it whenever possible.

EDIT

If the vector is never modified, then it is okay to use it globally, but in that case it should be constant.

Comment: Can you explain more about Why using global variable lead to serious problems because we can save memory as we don't need to pass it in recursion call?

Comment: @Ashishkumar global variables, if they are not const will have their own life. The more code you have, the more secrets they will have. Since all functions can change them, some of them will. The larger the program and the more the number of programmers are working on it, the more confusion you will get. Surely, it "works", but will lead to a lot of bugs and head scratching. The problem is that their context is practically infinite. Read more here: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/4-2a-why-global-variables-are-evil/

Comment: I got your point. I have modified my question too. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Ashishkumar you are welcome. I have edited my answer. If this answer solves your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.